# Looping through AGOL services with arcrest

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-online, arcrest

[Using this example](http://anothergisblog.blogspot.com/2014/10/using-arcrest-to-export-hosted-feature.html) I am trying to loop through my Arcgis Online account using `ArcREST` in order to download feature layers locally.  However I have not been able to drill down into each folder to acquire each service name with `.content` in order to run the `.exportItem`.  I can get the folder names but I can't get access to the `feature layers` in the folders.

```
import os
import arcpy as env
import arcrest
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\xxx\temp"
uname = "xxx"
pword = "xxx"

site = "http://xxx.xxx.arcgis.com"

sh = arcrest.AGOLTokenSecurityHandler(uname,pword,site)
admin = arcrest.manageorg.administration.Administration(securityHandler=sh)

content = admin.content
user = content.users.user(uname)

for folder in user.folders:
    print folder
    #This line below was added after original post
    for sub_folder in folder:
       print sub_folder
```

Edit: added a `for loop` within the original loop to attempt to access the contents of the folders.  The variable `sub_folder` prints only the contents of the root folder

Comment: You are saying that you cannot get access to features in subfolders. What is the response you get from the script?

Comment: It only prints the items in the root folder it does not loop through the contents of the other folders...i[title] returns all folder names  but user.items only returns the roots content.  i.items does the same. I need to be able to get to the contents of the folders to export them.

Comment: You also need to loop the subfolders in order to get the contents. 
Try to create a new for-loop in the existing one. Let me know if you need any help with it.

Comment: access to the sub folders is my question..Your help would be appreciated

Comment: Here is a start:

`for folder in user.folders:

    for subfolder in folder:

        print subfolder.items`

Comment: Same result edited OP

Comment: it's `sub_folder.items`

Comment: That's not an option subfolder does not have the attribute `items`

Comment: @Stefan you seem to have inadvertently made a comment in the area reserved for direct answers to the question and so I will convert it to one.

Comment: @Dan Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications rather than creating a comment trail that potential answerers may or may not read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to accomplish this solely with `ArcREST`.  I solved it by creating a list with the urls to the folder.  Which gave me the ability to perform actions on the `Feature Services` located within folders

```
p = {"f": "pjson", "token": token}
token = sh.token

url = []
for folder in user.folders:
    fld_id = str(folder['id'])
    user = str(folder['username'])
    fldr = root_url + "/users/" + user + "/" + fld_id 
    url.append(fldr)



for each in opp_url:
    #print each
    get = requests.get(each, params=p)
    obj = get.json()
    for fs in obj['items']:
        if fs['type'] == 'Feature Service':
            titelid = fs['title']
            exportedItemId = fs['id']
            print exportedItemId
            #Continue doing some operation on Feature Services once ids are obtained
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured this out...

```
admin = arcrest.manageorg.administration.Administration(securityHandler=sh)
content = admin.content
user = content.users.user(uname)

# Iterate through all content in each folder
for folder in user.folders:
    fName = folder['title']
    user.currentFolder = fName
    print ('--------------------------------------------')
    print ("In Folder: {}".format(fName))
    for item in user.items:
        print " - {}".format(item.title)
```